# Pass NULL column value through Shell Script

Tags: shell

My shell script is calling a Procedure to perform some operations. I have a column in the Procedural call which has default value of NULL, so I want to pass NULL value through my Shell script. I am getting "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
'INSERT_GROUP' " exception when I execute the Shell script.

Procedure signature:-

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE INSERT_GROUP (
col_1     IN NUMBER,
col_2     IN VARCHAR2,
col_3     IN VARCHAR2,
col_4     IN VARCHAR2,
col_5     IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,                                             
col_6     IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'A',                                        
**col_7     IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,** 
col_8     OUT NUMBER,
col_9     OUT VARCHAR2 )
```

Now col_7 has default value NULL. And I want my shell script to pass NULL value to this Procedure call.

Shell script code where Procedure is called:-

```
echo "Exec INSERT_GROUP($col_1_val,'"$col_2_val"','"$col_3_val"','"$col_4_val"',0,'"col_5_val"',NULL);" >> exec_sp.txt
echo "EXIT" >> exec_sp.txt
```

Im getting the ORA error while passing NULL in the col_7 value.

How do I go around solving this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: almost certainly ora is reading your text value NULL as a string, which violates the definition for col_7. The shell will think it has something as a positional parameter if you use a pair of quote chars, either `''` or `""`. You may have to further escape those like `\'\'` or as many as 5 preceding \ chars, depending on the exact nature of how you're calling the script etc. As long as you can get `''` in your `exec_sp.txt` file, it should work. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks...have resolved the issue.